# Scatter pie chart on map in Plotly or Bokeh in Python

Tags: python, plotly, bokeh, scatter-plot

Is there a possibility to create a scatter plot on a map within Plotly or Bokeh to make every single scatter point a mini pie chart? I can't find info in docs of plotly.graph_objects.Scattermapbox and bokeh.plotting.

Comment: It's not different from just creating N pie charts, and you definitely can do it in Bokeh. Just like in this example at https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/pie_chart.html only with multiple calls to `wedge`, each with its own `x`, `y`, `source`, and maybe other fields.

Comment: Any luck using Scattermapbox? Looking for the same here.

Comment: Bokeh is the solution, will paste sample code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Bokeh in version 2.3.0 has been the solution (old versions will probably work too).
You can find working example on [sarswpolsce.pl](https://sarswpolsce.pl/?page_id=7)
Usage of p.wedge presented in [this use-case](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/pie_chart.html) is life-saving.

Here is pseudocode for desired effect:

```
    p = figure(x_range=(mercator_x_min, mercator_x_max),
               y_range=(mercator_y_min, mercator_y_max),
               x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator",
               tools=TOOLS, output_backend="webgl", #for faster rendering
               plot_width = plot_w, plot_height = plot_h,
               title = "title")
    
    p.add_tile(tile_provider)
    
    for w in coordinates.keys():
        lat, lon = converter(coordinates[w][0], coordinates[w][1])
        renderdict[w] = p.wedge(x=lon, y=lat, radius=radius_, alpha = alpha_,
                                start_angle=cumsum(f'Angle_{w}', include_zero=True),
                                end_angle=cumsum(f'Angle_{w}'),
                                line_color="white", fill_color=f'Color_{w}',
                                legend_field= legend,
                                source=data_source, name = w)
```